# Emacs relative and absolute line number at the same time?

Tags: line-numbers

I don't mean hybrid line number mode, I want the absolute line number appears for all the lines, not only the current line number.

Comment: can you post an example?

Comment: See this related thread:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36149/show-both-relative-and-absolute-line-numbers-in-emacs-26

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to this? And why isn't the hybrid mode good enough for your purpose?

Answer (score 1):

`display-line-numbers-mode` to display line numbers for the current buffer.

`global-display-line-numbers-mode` to display line numbers for all buffers.

Answer (score 0):

This is done in the [linum-relative](https://github.com/coldnew/linum-relative) package

Comment: Is https://github.com/coldnew/linum-relative/issues/4 implemented? It looks like what the OP is asking for, but it's still open...

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood you. No, having both relative and absolute line numbers for all lines is not implemented. I thought you meant "current line as absolute, rest as relative"

Comment: Emacs 26 will offer native line number support: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/6hux6a/native_display_of_line_numbers/

Comment: care to explain how to get absolute line number on current line but relative line numbers on the rest of the lines? It sounded like that's what you were referring to, but I didn't see any way of doing that in the github README for linum-relative

Comment: In the [Setup & Tips](https://github.com/coldnew/linum-relative#setup--tips) section, it says that activating `linum-mode` should be enough _given that you have installed the package_