# Show both relative and absolute line numbers in Emacs 26

Tags: linum-mode, line-numbers, emacs26

One of the [new features in Emacs 26](https://pastebin.com/ptwgn7YB) is `display-line-numbers-mode`:

```
Emacs now supports optional display of line numbers in the buffer.
This is similar to what linum-mode provides, but much faster and
doesn't usurp the display margin for the line numbers.  Customize the
buffer-local variable 'display-line-numbers' to activate this optional
display.  Alternatively, you can use the `display-line-numbers-mode'
minor mode or the global `global-display-line-numbers-mode'.  When
using these modes, customize `display-line-numbers-type' with the same
value as you would use with `display-line-numbers'.
```

Up to now, I've been using [linum-relativenumber](https://github.com/scottjad/linum-relativenumber) to get both relative and absolute line numbers at the same time.  Here is how it looks:

[image]

Now that the new `display-line-numbers-mode` feature is here, with promises to be much faster, I thought maybe I could switch to using that instead.

But I haven't been able to figure out how to get it to show both relative and absolute line numbers, since the help for `display-line-numbers-type` points to `display-line-number`, which says:

```
Non-nil means display line numbers.
If the value is t, display the absolute number of each line of a buffer
shown in a window.  Absolute line numbers count from the beginning of
the current narrowing, or from buffer beginning.  If the value is
‘relative’, display for each line not containing the window’s point its
relative number instead, i.e. the number of the line relative to the
line showing the window’s point.
```

and there doesn't seem to be a `both` setting.

Can anyone suggest a way to get both relative and abolute line numbers using the new `display-line-numbers-mode` feature?

Comment: Do the proposed settings in [this comment of mine](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19532/hybrid-line-number-mode-in-emacs#comment56950_19532) result in the desired behaviour?

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't do quite what I want.  It shows the absolute line number of the current line and relative line numbers of the rest, but I want to see both the relative and absolute line numbers of every line (in two columns, right next to each other).  [Here](https://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/496408linummode.png) is how I'd like it to look (which is how it does look with linum-mode when using the linum-relativenumber package, but I'd like to do it with the native Emacs 26 `display-line-numbers-mode` instead.

Comment: Ah, native line numbers can't do this on their own, but since they are in-buffer, leaving the margin/fringe free, you can enable them at the same time as other packages, e.g. `nlinum` or similar.

Comment: Since this thread is related to https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/29325/emacs-relative-and-absolute-line-number-at-the-same-time, I wanted to post a comment joining the two.